# Getting error on if and elif

Tags: python

Does anyone know why I keep getting an error with this section of my code?

```
 if db_orientation2 =="Z":
            a="/C=C\"
 elif db_orientation2=="E":
            a="\C=C\"
```

This is the error:

```
File "<ipython-input-7-25cda51c429e>", line 11
    a="/C=C\"
         ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

The `elif` is highlighted as red as if the operation is not allowed...

Comment: The error message points to the line **before** the `elif`.

Answer (score 4):

String literals cannot end with a backslash. You'll have to double it:

```
a="/C=C\\"
#       ^
```

The highlighting of your code also clearly shows the problem.

Comment: Oh I see, but the second backslash will not appear in the string, right?

Comment: @vluos Asking that question means you don't understand the general concept of escaping. This is common in programming, I suggest you research it.

Comment: @vluos Yes, it won't be part of the string