# Concatenate path and filename

Tags: python, path, filepath

I have to build the full path together in python. I tried this:

```
filename= "myfile.odt"

subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.exe',
                    '--headless',
                    '--convert-to',
                    'pdf', '--outdir',
                    r'C:\Users\A\Desktop\Repo\',
                    r'C:\Users\A\Desktop\Repo\'+filename])
```

But I get this error

> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal.

Comment: String literals can't end with a single ``\``, else you'll be escaping the `'` which leaves the string  *open*

Comment: Also notice the highlighting of the string http://stackoverflow.com/a/40053376/3125566

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Backslash character (`\`) has to be escaped in string literals.

- This is wrong: `'\'`
- This is correct: `'\\'` - this is a string containing one backslash

Therefore, this is wrong:

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.exe'
```

#### There is a trick!

String literals prefixed by `r` are meant for easier writing of regular expressions. One of their features is that backslash characters do not have to be escaped. So, this would be OK:

```
r'C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.exe'
```

However, that wont work for a string ending in backslash:

- `r'\'` - this is a syntax error

So, this is also wrong:

```
r'C:\Users\A\Desktop\Repo\'
```

So, I would do the following:

```
import os
import subprocess


soffice = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LibreOffice 5\\program\\soffice.exe'
outdir = 'C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\Repo\\'
full_path = os.path.join(outdir, filename)

subprocess.call([soffice,
                 '--headless',
                 '--convert-to', 'pdf',
                 '--outdir', outdir,
                 full_path])
```

Answer (score 33):

Try:

```
import os
os.path.join('C:\Users\A\Desktop\Repo', filename)
```

The os module contains many useful methods for directory and path manipulation

Comment: It's good to use os joining, but the real issue here is the ' is being escaped.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that your raw string is ending with a single backslash. For reason I don't understand, this is not allowed. You can either double up the slash at the end:

```
r'C:\Users\A\Desktop\Repo\\'+filename
```

or use `os.path.join()`, which is the preferred method:

```
os.path.join(r'C:\Users\A\Desktop\Repo', filename)
```

Comment: Well my guess why a trailing backslash is not allowed would be that it escapes the closing quote. I haven't looked this up, but while `r''` allows one to write backslashes without escaping, you still need a way to escape a single quote in there, so `\'` is still an escaped quote and the single-quoted string continues to the next single quote. This is consistent with the syntax error because the interpreter thought it's reading a string when the file ended.

Answer (score 2):

To build on what zanseb said, use the os.path.join, but also \ is an escape character, so your string literal can't end with a \ as it would escape the ending quote.

```
import os
os.path.join(r'C:\Users\A\Desktop\Repo', filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

To anyone else stumbling across this question, you can use `\` to concatenate a `Path` object and `str`.

Use `path.Path` for paths compatible with *both* Unix and Windows (you can use it the same way as I've used `pathlib.PureWindowsPath`).

The only reason I'm using `pathlib.PureWindowsPath` is that the question asked specifically about Windows paths.

For example:

```
import pathlib
# PureWindowsPath enforces Windows path style
# for paths that work on both Unix and Windows use path.Path
base_dir = pathlib.PureWindowsPath(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program')
# elegant path concatenation
myfile = base_dir / "myfile.odt"

print(myfile)
>>> C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\myfile.odt
```

Comment: 1. Your first sentence uses backslash but your code uses forward slash (`/`). 2. The `/` operator does not simply *concatenate* the second argument, it performs a **path join**. If you actually just want to append a string, `/` will not work.

Answer (score 1):

add library to code :

```
from pathlib import Path
```

when u want **get current path without filename** use this method :

```
print("Directory Path:", Path().absolute())
```

now you just need to add the file name to it :for example

```
   mylink = str(Path().absolute())+"/"+"filename.etc" #str(Path().absolute())+"/"+"hello.txt"
```

If normally addes to the first path "r" character
for example: r"c://..."

***You do not need to do  here***

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply add the strings together. Personally I like this more.

```
filename = r"{}{}{}".format(dir, foldername, filename)
```