# Loop through folders in dir python

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, directory

I need to store the directory for each folder within holding_folder in a list.

```
C:\users\documents\holding_folder
```

within this folder I have hundreds of folders like:

```
Raw data 3543
Raw data 4565
Raw data 4677
```

however when I click on each folder there are empty folders until I get to the final folder with data.

example:

```
raw data 3543\sub\supersub\P3543
```

Folder P3543 has all the data. sub and supersub folders exist in each 'raw data xxxx folder'. The same 4 digits on the `raw data xxxx` are on the `Pxxxx` folder.

The first thing I did was pull the last 4 digits for each folder within the holding_folder using:

```
main_dir = os.listdir(r'C:\users\documents\holding_folder')
numeric_values = [x[-4:] for x in main_dir]
```

then I tried concatenating the string onto the two parts that I need to but received invalid syntax error:

```
final_paths= [(r'C:\users\documents\holding_folder' + str(x) + '\sub\supersub\P' + str(x)) for x in numeric_values]
```

I even tried something with `os.path.join` per recommendation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596748/concatenate-path-and-filename), but I am getting an invalid syntax error:

```
final_paths = [(os.path.join(r'C:\users\documents\holding_folder' + str(x) + '\sub\supersub\P' + str(x))) for x in numeric_values]
```

I also tried `\\` instead of the singe `\` but then each file path had two slashes. Example:

```
C:\\users\\documents\\holding_folder\\raw data 3543\\sub\\supersub\\P3543
```

my final desired output is this:

```
['C:\users\documents\holding_folder\3543\sub\supersub\P3543',
 'C:\users\documents\holding_folder\4565\sub\supersub\P4565',
 'C:\users\documents\holding_folder\4677\sub\supersub\P4677' ]
```

Any help with this would be great. I am not sure what I am missing.

I am ultimately trying to iterate through each file path. This is why I want to store each path in a list. using:

```
for item in list:
    os.chdir(item)
```

Comment: You are missing a `+` after one of the `str(x)` in both of your cases.

Comment: There are no words to describe how much I hate myself

Comment: don't, just delete your question.

Comment: With that correction, I now get the double \\ results when using `os.path.join` or with the string concatenation.

Comment: When I attempt to loop through my list with double slashes, I get an error `The system cannot find the path specified:`