# How to concat a path + filename in python?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to write a function in Python, that concatenates `path + filename`:

```
import os 

ruta_proyecto = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

def ejecutar_sql(archivo, parametro):
    sp.ejecutar_archivo(f"{ruta_proyecto}{archivo}", parametro)
```

But if I try to add `"/ invert*` " in the function, it returns an error.

How can I concatenate `{ruta_proyecto} + "/ invert"* + {archivo}`.

Comment: Use `os.path.join()`

Comment: [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate path and filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596748/concatenate-path-and-filename)

Comment: What error is the function returning when you add that new bit? In fact, you need to show us the code of *that* function, not the code of the working function.

Comment: Hi Barmar and Olvin Roght, Thanks for your answer, thiw worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments of Barmar and Olvin Roght, I have resolved the problem. This is the answer:

```
def ejecutar_sql(archivo, parametro):
     sp.ejecutar_archivo(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),f'{archivo}' ), parametro)
```